# How to fix graphical glitch in Chromium?

Tags: 15.04, intel-graphics, chromium

I am using Chromium 45 on Ubuntu 15.04 on a Thinkpad X230. Each time I am opening a new tab, I am presented with the following graphical glitch:

[image]

Has someone experienced this irritating glitch and knows how to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

I apologise for this question. The problem was caused by the Chrome extension [Empty New Tab Page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/empty-new-tab-page/dpjamkmjmigaoobjbekmfgabipmfilij). It removed the `New Tab` tab title and thus left this black glitch behind.

Alternatively, users can install [New Tab Page - Blank](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-page-blank/nenecpikdapoaemacjppaimlcgknbijk/related) which preserves the tab name.